# Unity Facebook SDK, can't retrieve Country from Dictionary after Login

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am retrieving the country of a facebook user as following:

```
 void Get()
    {
        FB.API("/me?fields=location{location{country}}", HttpMethod.GET,this.callback1);
    }

    private void callback1(IResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("FB.API result = null");
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(result.RawResult) as Dictionary<string, object>;
    }
}
```

This works fine.

JSON looks like:

```
{
  "location": {
    "location": {
      "country": "England"
    },
    "id": "111122233344"
  },
  "id": "1112299000"
}
```

Problem is that the `dict` result is like nested dictionary, i can't find straightforward way to retrieve the country name.

Comment: Added Json example in the question.  Just need to retrieve the country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this end to end, drawing from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/Json/) it should look like this:

```
var dict = Json.Deserialize(jsonString) as Dictionary<string,object>;

object locationH;
string country;
if(dict.TryGetValue ("location", out locationH)) {
  var location = (((Dictionary<string, object>)locationH) ["location"]);
  var countryDict = (((Dictionary<string, object>)location) ["country"]);
  country = (string)countryDict;
}
```